# What is a verb to describe the act of making a grammatical error?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

Making a spelling mistake is called "misspelling".

It obviously can't be "misgrammaring"...

Here's the full context:

> “codes”. This might be considered a “minor grammatical error”, only it isn't. This book deals with code... our profession is creating code. Being a web developer makes you interact with thousands of people online over time, everyone saying “code”, the right way. Why consistently misspell or make a grammatical error with this?

I'd like to condense *make a grammatical error with* into a single word, a verb that describes the act of "misgrammaring".

Comment: Grammatical error?

Comment: If the sample paragraph is about a person referring to a group of programs as *codes* (rather than *code*), that is not an error; it is use of acceptable but uncommon nomenclature.  Being uncommon does not make it wrong.

Comment: No. A line of code like this: `<?php $ugly_code = "But can't do much about it."; ?>` is also called "codes" in this book. Even in the few cases where the usage is permissible, I believe conformity is the better approach considering the book is meant for English speaking audiences.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Solecism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/solecism#Noun)* (in the sense “Error in the use of language”), a rather general term that encompasses grammar mistakes, is one possibility.  Another general term is *[infelicity](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/infelicity)*.  A few dozen quite-specific kinds of language errors (mostly stylistic rather than grammatical) are explained in BYU's [Stylistic Vices](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/Groupings/Vices.htm) webpage, for example *[pleonasm](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/P/pleonasm.htm)*,  “Use of more words than is necessary semantically. Rhetorical repetition that is grammatically superfluous” or *[acyrologia](http://rhetoric.byu.edu/Figures/A/acyrologia.htm)*,  “An incorrect use of words, especially the use of words that sound alike but are far in meaning from the speaker's intentions” (like *[malapropism](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/malapropism#Noun)*, *[eggcorns](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/eggcorn#Noun)*, etc) and many more.

For verbs, consider  *[misspeak](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/misspeak)* (“To fail to pronounce, utter, or speak correctly”).   A [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Misspeaking) called *Misspeaking* says

> Misspeaking is a word used to describe the act of speaking “incorrectly, unclearly, or misleadingly”, to “fail to convey the meaning one intends by one’s words”

Also consider the form *to err grammatically*.  Verb *[err](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/err#Verb)* means to make a mistake; to err grammatically is to make a mistake in grammar.

Comment: Is there a verb I can use? For example: `What makes a person consistently misspell or *make a grammatical error* with this?`. I want to condense the 4 words to one.

Comment: Thanks for answering, upvoted. I've updated my question with full context, if it would help with answering...

Comment: To err is human; to _err grammatically_ answers the O.P.'s question.

Comment: @J.R., I agree. Considering that there is no single word for this,  saying `Why consistently misspell or err grammatically with this?` is the best I can do.

Comment: Actually, my remark was meant to be humorous, a play off a [famous quote](http://www.brainyquote.com/quotes/quotes/a/alexanderp101451.html). I think better ways to say it would include `Why consistently misspell or make grammatical errors?` and `Why continue to make grammar and spelling mistakes?`